# Pass "yes" to command given in a text file

Tags: ruby, vsphere, rbvmomi

I'm using [`rbvmomi`](https://github.com/rlane/rbvmomi) gem to automate vsphere in ruby. I'm using vmware API StartProgramInGuest to run commands. The commands are given in a text file which is passed as an argument to GuestProgramSpec. One of the commands in the file requires a confirmation. Since the commands are passed in a text file, I'm not sure how to pass "yes" to the command. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 gom = vim.serviceContent.guestOperationsManager

    guest_auth = RbVmomi::VIM::NamePasswordAuthentication(
      :interactiveSession => false,
      :username => "user",
      :password => "pass"
    )

    prog_spec = RbVmomi::VIM::GuestProgramSpec(
      :programPath =>"/opt/system/bin/ssh",
      :arguments => "-s /opt/system/etc/cli/default/main.par -f /home/admin/local.txt"
    )

    id = gom.processManager.StartProgramInGuest(
      :vm => vm, :auth => guest_auth, :spec => prog_spec
    )
```

Contents of local.txt :

```
show version > /home/admin/veriosn-1.txt
application upgrade appbundle.tar.gz local
show version > /home/admin/version-2.txt
```

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code

Comment: It would be fine whether you’d’ve a content of `local.txt` shown. What command you want to pass `yes` to? I bet this command accepts `-y` argument to silently accept everything. We are not a fortunetellers here, after all.

Comment: It's an upgrade command. It asks if we want to save the configuration before proceeding. The default is yes. So pressing enter would also be fine.

Comment: Does `upgrade` accepts **a command line parameter `-y`**? I believe it does.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't.